# This pagination script is doodoo - I need a better one!

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I was looking at the pagination script (posted below) and found it to be gros,s and not very good at all especially when trying to customize it.

This is what the main page looks like:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$per_page = 9;

//Calculating no of pages
$sql = "select * from messages";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$pages = ceil($count/$per_page)
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_pagination.js"></script>

<div id="loading" ></div>
<div id="content" ></div>
<ul id="pagination">
<?php
//Pagination Numbers
for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{
echo '<li id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

The top part of the code gets the results from the mysql db and than uses this information to display the numbers in the body of this page.

I am trying to put something like this on a separate page like count_page.php and then just include it.

I guess my question is, if there is a better way of doing the above with better structure. A better way to go through the db and count the results and display the appropriate numbers. The above seems messy.

Thanks for any help or suggestions on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is very useful pagination class.
it is simple, you'll understand, i'm sure

```
class PS_Pagination {
    var $php_self;
    var $rows_per_page = 10; //Number of records to display per page
    var $total_rows = 0; //Total number of rows returned by the query
    var $links_per_page = 5; //Number of links to display per page
    var $append = ""; //Paremeters to append to pagination links
    var $sql = "";
    var $debug = false;
    var $conn = false;
    var $page = 1;
    var $max_pages = 0;
    var $offset = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param resource $connection Mysql connection link
     * @param string $sql SQL query to paginate. Example : SELECT * FROM users
     * @param integer $rows_per_page Number of records to display per page. Defaults to 10
     * @param integer $links_per_page Number of links to display per page. Defaults to 5
     * @param string $append Parameters to be appended to pagination links 
     */

    function PS_Pagination($connection, $sql, $rows_per_page = 10, $links_per_page = 5, $append = "") {
        $this->conn = $connection;
        $this->sql = $sql;
        $this->rows_per_page = (int)$rows_per_page;
        if (intval($links_per_page ) > 0) {
            $this->links_per_page = (int)$links_per_page;
        } else {
            $this->links_per_page = 5;
        }
        $this->append = $append;
        $this->php_self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
        if (isset($_GET['page'] )) {
            $this->page = intval($_GET['page'] );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes the SQL query and initializes internal variables
     *
     * @access public
     * @return resource
     */
    function paginate() {
        //Check for valid mysql connection
        if (! $this->conn || ! is_resource($this->conn )) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "MySQL connection missing<br />";
            return false;
        }

        //Find total number of rows
        $all_rs = @mysql_query($this->sql );
        if (! $all_rs) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "SQL query failed. Check your query.<br /><br />Error Returned: " . mysql_error();
            return false;
        }
        $this->total_rows = mysql_num_rows($all_rs );
        @mysql_close($all_rs );

        //Return FALSE if no rows found
        if ($this->total_rows == 0) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "Query returned zero rows.";
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Max number of pages
        $this->max_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->rows_per_page );
        if ($this->links_per_page > $this->max_pages) {
            $this->links_per_page = $this->max_pages;
        }

        //Check the page value just in case someone is trying to input an aribitrary value
        if ($this->page > $this->max_pages || $this->page <= 0) {
            $this->page = 1;
        }

        //Calculate Offset
        $this->offset = $this->rows_per_page * ($this->page - 1);

        //Fetch the required result set
        $rs = @mysql_query($this->sql . " LIMIT {$this->offset}, {$this->rows_per_page}" );
        if (! $rs) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "Pagination query failed. Check your query.<br /><br />Error Returned: " . mysql_error();
            return false;
        }
        return $rs;
    }

    /**
     * Display the link to the first page
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to 'First'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderFirst($tag = 'First') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page == 1) {
            return "$tag ";
        } else {
            return '<a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=1&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a> ';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the link to the last page
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to 'Last'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderLast($tag = 'Last') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page == $this->max_pages) {
            return $tag;
        } else {
            return ' <a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . $this->max_pages . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the next link
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to '>>'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderNext($tag = '&gt;&gt;') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page < $this->max_pages) {
            return '<a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . ($this->page + 1) . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        } else {
            return $tag;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the previous link
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to '<<'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderPrev($tag = '&lt;&lt;') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page > 1) {
            return ' <a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . ($this->page - 1) . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        } else {
            return " $tag";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the page links
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    function renderNav($prefix = '<span class="page_link">', $suffix = '</span>') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        $batch = ceil($this->page / $this->links_per_page );
        $end = $batch * $this->links_per_page;
        if ($end == $this->page) {
            //$end = $end + $this->links_per_page - 1;
        //$end = $end + ceil($this->links_per_page/2);
        }
        if ($end > $this->max_pages) {
            $end = $this->max_pages;
        }
        $start = $end - $this->links_per_page + 1;
        $links = '';

        for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i ++) {
            if ($i == $this->page) {
                $links .= $prefix . " $i " . $suffix;
            } else {
                $links .= ' ' . $prefix . '<a href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . $i . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $i . '</a>' . $suffix . ' ';
            }
        }

        return $links;
    }

    /**
     * Display full pagination navigation
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    function renderFullNav() {
        return $this->renderFirst() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderPrev() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderNav() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderNext() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderLast();
    }

    /**
     * Set debug mode
     *
     * @access public
     * @param bool $debug Set to TRUE to enable debug messages
     * @return void
     */
    function setDebug($debug) {
        $this->debug = $debug;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot better than the one I had.